# Membership.GetUser throwing MissingMethodException after upgrade from EF5 to EF6 in my Razor file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I upgraded my MVC4 web app from EF5 to EF6 and I'm sure that my error is related to this.

I have some code to retrieve the email of the currently logged in user within my razor file which is as follows

```
@Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).Email
```

This was working but directly after upgrading to EF6 I now get the following exception

> Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.

Why is this?  What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 doesn't have System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext

Get the new NuGet package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core/2.0.0

Comment: thanks, that did the job (I had to update the web config to point to the web.providers v2 but that works now).  So I guess that web.providers 1 uses the old EF